# Fluid simulation not working after scaling the domain

Tags: fluid-simulation

So I just notice that If I scale up the domain of the fluid simulation and bake again the fluid it doesn't work... I tried applying the scale and I tried without applying same thing.
Is there any reason why this is happening ?

Comment: increase resolution divisions and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure without more information, I've had similar issues where the domain clearly looks deformed despite the scale being cleared.

Removing the Domain under physics properties and re-adding it to the object still wouldn't work.

My solution to this has been to delete the object and remake the domain. Remember to add your material back onto the new domain if you do this.

I rarely run into this issue. I'm not sure what causes it, but it could be a bug.